# Netbeans 7.x - change editor identation

Tags: netbeans

Is it possible to change the indentation on the Netbeans 7.x IDE editor? I prefer to use a single indentation, but Netbeans always uses 2, which makes some of my PHP files a bit hard to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit code formatting and tabulation in:

Tools -> Options -> Editor -> Formatting

[image]